# How to unindent after Org list

Tags: org-mode, evil, indentation

GNU Emacs     v29.2
Doom core     v3.0.0-pre
Doom modules  v23.12.0-pre

So I want to RET/return after some bullet point lists and no longer be indented, but this is my current issue and I don't know how to stop indentation:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJGz0.png]

I'm using org version 9.7

doom/info output:

```
generated  Feb 01, 2024 10:12:44
system     MacOS 14.3 Darwin 23.3.0 arm64 ns
emacs      29.2 /Users/$USER/.emacs.d/
doom       3.0.0-pre PROFILE=_@0 grafted, HEAD -> master ff33ec8 2024-01-28 00:49:06
           -0500 /Users/$USER/.doom.d/
shell      /bin/zsh
features   ACL GLIB GMP GNUTLS JPEG JSON LCMS2 LIBXML2 MODULES NATIVE_COMP NOTIFY
           KQUEUE NS PDUMPER PNG RSVG SQLITE3 THREADS TIFF TOOLKIT_SCROLL_BARS
           TREE_SITTER XIM ZLIB
traits     gui server-running envvar-file
modules    :config use-package :completion company vertico :ui doom doom-dashboard
           hl-todo modeline ophints (popup +defaults) (vc-gutter +pretty)
           vi-tilde-fringe workspaces :editor (evil +everywhere) file-templates fold
           snippets :emacs dired electric undo vc :checkers syntax :tools (eval
           +overlay) lookup magit :os macos :lang emacs-lisp markdown org sh :config
           (default +bindings +smartparens)
packages   (org-bullets)
```

Comment: How did you type lines 7-16? Lists are supposed to end after two consecutive `RET`s, so the third `RET` is supposed to end the list and start a new paragraph. Alternatively if you don't want blank lines after the list, press `RET` at the end of the final list item, then delete the indentation (either with `BACKSPACE` or `C-\ `) and start typing your paragraph. Try it with `emacs -Q`: if that works, but it doesn't work in Doom, open an issue with Doom.

Comment: See [Plain Lists](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-Lists.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems you are not using a list key character.

The Screenshot indicates a nested heading but no list (ordered or unordered) at all. If you are below a heading there is no possibility to have text that is not counted as the headings information. So you can basically use headings as list but it has it's limits.

Make sure zu use `-`  to start a list. Other possible options are `1.` and `+`.

Examples:

```
- first item
- second item
  - first item of second item
    Additional text
- third item



+ first item
+ second item
  - first item of second item
    Additional text
+ third item
```

https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-Lists.html

Comment: This is really helpful to know generally thank you! I was just not using it correctly as you pointed out. I also in the meantime found a workaround with what I was doing with headings in my question whereby I  added this into my config.el:

`(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-indent-mode 0)))`

To disable indents for org mode altogether, visually it still looks the same to me other than a bit of visual unindenting, are there any other implication of using this setting I might not be aware of? I'm really grateful for your help!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I get what you want but probably you are looking for `(setq org-adapt-indentation nil)`

Comment: Also make sure if this realy fits your needs as you will anyways add _all_ the additional text to the last subheading above the text. Have a look at how it really looks if you export it to html for example with `C-c C-e h o`. That gives you a good view how Org mode is interpreting your notes if it had to share it

Comment: Good catch! It never crossed my mind that those were headline markers, not list markers.